# TFS 2015.1: new process templates missing

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-process-template

Recently we upgraded from TFS 2013.2 (german) to TFS 2015.1 (english). Now if I create a new project collection and a new team project I can only select the old german process templates

```
"Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 2013.2"
"MSF for Agile Software Development 2013.2"
"MSF for CMMI Process Improvement 2013.2"
```

The description below the templates is in german, consequently I believe I have only the old process templates installed on our TFS.

I found the correct templates here:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 14.0\Tools\Deploy\ProcessTemplateManagerFiles\1033
```

How can I re-install the original current process templates from TFS 2015.1 in english?

Where are the active templates stored? In the database? Can I "inject" the correct ones somehow?

Deleting and re-importing the templates is not possible because TFS locks the default templates now. Unfortunately the wrong default templates...

Answer (score 2):

You can upload these project templates in Visual Studio under **Team -> Team Project Collection Settings -> Process Template Manager** and there is an upload button.

The problem that you are going to face is that any projects currently using one of the older templates will not be transferable to the new ones.

You should be able to remove the old ones from this window also provided that there are no projects using them.

Comment: TFS 2015 does no allow uploading original process templates: https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/work/guidance/changes-to-process-templates. I have to rename the default templates and change their GUID to add them to a collection. In addition any new collection I create will NOT have the current templates. In my opinion this is quite clearly a bug...